# Rails - Always have to check exists, and then value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am checking to see if a value in a related table exists quite often in my view, in this case, expenses have approvals.  If they have not been submitted, then there is no record of them in the approvals table.

I am ending up with some really awkward code

```
<% if !expense_item.expense_approval || expense_item.expense_approval.approval_status == 0 %>
```

Is there a way to do an if statement on a value, without having to check if it exists first?  Or some default way to set it nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following in your `ExpenseItem` model:

```
delegate :approval_status, :to => :expense_approval, :allow_nil => true
```

This should allow you to simply do the following:

```
if expense_item.approval_status == 0
```

The try method above certainly works, but I like delegation better because I don't have to have `.try(...)` all over my code.

Comment: +1 from a guy called Demeter, the other answer is correct but this match the case much better

Answer (score 3):

you can use try method which will return nil if method passed doesn't exist. so you could do something like:

```
expense_item.expense_approval.try(:approval_status) == 0
```

Comment: ah, fantastic, .try is my new friend!

Comment: Also check out Avdi Grrimms Confident Ruby talks/book he talks a lot about things like that